# Serving sample website using dart

Tags: dart, dart-io

I just started learning dart, and what I wanted to do as practice is to serve the default web application with a simple webserver. I store the server at `E:\DartProject\server` and the web client at `E:\DartProject\WebClient`. Unfortunately I can't get the server to serve the webapp. The code for the webserver is

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart' show VirtualDirectory;


VirtualDirectory virDir = new VirtualDirectory("E:\DartProject\WebClient\web");

void main() {
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 80).then((server) {
    print("Serving at ${server.address}:${server.port}");
    server.listen((request) {
      virDir.serveRequest(request);
    });
  });
}
```

I'm always getting 404 errors. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes in your path may be being interpreted as escape characters?

Try changing `"E:\DartProject\WebClient\web"` to `r"E:\DartProject\WebClient\web"`, which will instruct Dart to interpret the whole string literally.

You also need to [configure a "default document"](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-by-example/#serving-indexhtml) if you're expected `/` to serve up `/index.html`, for example.

```
void directoryHandler(dir, request) {
  var indexUri = new Uri.file(dir.path).resolve('index.html');
  virDir.serveFile(new File(indexUri.toFilePath()), request);
}

void main() {
  virDir = new VirtualDirectory(r"E:\DartProject\WebClient\web")
    ..allowDirectoryListing = true
    ..directoryHandler = directoryHandler;

  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 8080).then((server) {
    print("Serving at ${server.address}:${server.port}");
    server.listen((request) {
      virDir.serveRequest(request);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DannyTuppeny. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I added `print('test')` under `virDir.serveRequest(request);` and every time i click refresh it writes test, but it does not serve the webclient. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you giving it a part to a file, or expecting it to default to something (like index.htm)?

Comment: @Lukasz See updated answer for how to get `/` to map to `/index.html`, assuming that might be what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @DannyTuppeny. Could you please add `..allowDirectoryListing = true` after `virDir = new VirtualDirectory(r"E:\DartProject\WebClient\web")`, this is required for it to work correctly.

Comment: @Lukasz Done! I actually removed that assuming it wouldn't be needed trying to keep the code more like your own! Doh!